# How are the assumptions used in the proof of Bourbaki-Alaoglu Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

This is a follow up question to a [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1504236/9464).

In the proof of the following theorem, where are the assumptions "Hausdorff" and "locally convex" used?

[image]

Comment: This is a good question. I don't think these two properties are used at all. But probably, the authors need the claim only under these assumptions later on?! Finally, why did you delete your answer to the other question? I think it is nice (I was wondering about linearity of $\varphi$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theorem says that

> If $X$ is a *Hausdorff locally convex space*, and $x,y$ are two distinct points in $X$, there exists $\lambda\in X^*$ such that $\varphi(x)\not=\varphi(y)$.

The assumption "Hausdorff locally convex space" is used to make $(X^*,X)$ as a dual pair.

In general, one has the following statement:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are in duality, then $V^\circ$ is compact in the topology $\sigma(Y,X)$ whenever $V$ is a neighborhood of zero in a locally convex topology compatible with the duality.